# MySQL SubQuery with multiple joins

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm fairly new to MySQL and have a problem with my SQL query.

**PROBLEM**

What I am trying to do is, get all the data from multiple tables via JOIN then from the returned results filter out the data using 'project_manager_id' and Search value from the parent query.

Notsure if I have things in the right order.

I would like to achieve this in one query.

```
/* FILTER OUT THE DATA BASED ON THE ID AND SEARCH VALUE */
SELECT j.project_manager_id 
FROM  tritech_reporting.job j
WHERE j.project_manager_id IN
(
/* SELECT ALL THE DATA */
SELECT j.id AS job_id, j.project_manager_id, j.request, j.total, j.est_labor_hours, j.est_gross_profit, j.act_labor_hours, j.remaining, c.id AS customerID, c.company_name, si.name AS site_name, cc.type
FROM tritech_reporting.job j 
INNER JOIN tritech_reporting.site si ON j.site_id = si.id 
INNER JOIN tritech_reporting.customer c ON j.customer_id = c.id
INNER JOIN tritech_reporting.cost_center cc ON j.id = cc.job_id 
WHERE cc.type = 'Product' OR cc.type = 'Monitoring' OR cc.type = 'Projects Direct' OR cc.type = 'Projects Indirect'
GROUP BY job_id
)
AND j.project_manager_id = 7
AND c.company_name = '%spot%'
ORDER BY job_id DESC;
```

**CURRENTLY RETURNS**

```
Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

**OUTCOME**

The outcome would be to have the data filtered from the mass of results.

Currently the inner Sql query returns data, simplified below:

```
job_id | project_manager_id | request   | total
5001   | 380                | Tech test | 3,454.56
5003   | 7                  | Spotless  | 3,454.56
5031   | 380                | Tech test | 3,454.56
5041   | 7                  | Spot Free | 3,454.56
5033   | 380                | Tech test | 3,454.56
```

After the outer filter runs:

```
job_id | project_manager_id | request   | total
5001   | 7                  | Spotless  | 3,454.56
5001   | 7                  | Spot Free | 3,454.56
```

Comment: Please add sample data and the expected result

Comment: Please explain "doesn't work" in technical terms. Also don't self-deprecate. Everyone hear is learning.

Comment: Your query does not make sense. You filter on 

    `AND j.project_manager_id = 7`

but also want to do `j.project_manager_id IN ()`

Comment: I have updated my question. @juergend I know, that's why I'm here asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

You nested select should only select one column:

```
/* FILTER OUT THE DATA BASED ON THE ID AND SEARCH VALUE */
SELECT j.project_manager_id 
FROM  tritech_reporting.job j
WHERE j.project_manager_id IN
(
/* SELECT ALL THE DATA */
SELECT j.project_manager_id FROM tritech_reporting.job j 
INNER JOIN tritech_reporting.site si ON j.site_id = si.id 
INNER JOIN tritech_reporting.customer c ON j.customer_id = c.id
INNER JOIN tritech_reporting.cost_center cc ON j.id = cc.job_id 
WHERE cc.type = 'Product' OR cc.type = 'Monitoring' OR cc.type = 'Projects Direct' OR cc.type = 'Projects Indirect'
GROUP BY job_id
)
AND j.project_manager_id = 7
AND c.company_name = '%spot%'
ORDER BY job_id DESC;
```

Because you compare it with only one column

Comment: Thanks, While this did work in getting a list of the project_manager_id (id: 7) I still need the other data also, but not sure how to do this.

Comment: @JamesLawrie Than you have to select it with your outer select

Answer (score 0):

I manage to figure out the problem, I had the query back to front.
I changed the inner query to get the user and types and the outer to get everything else.

Here is the final working query.

```
/* FILTER OUT THE DATA BASED ON THE ID AND SEARCH VALUE */
SELECT j.id AS job_id, j.project_manager_id, j.request, j.total, 
 j.est_labor_hours, j.est_gross_profit, j.act_labor_hours, j.remaining, 
 c.id AS customerID, c.company_name, si.name AS site_name, cc.type 
FROM  tritech_reporting.job j
INNER JOIN tritech_reporting.site si ON j.site_id = si.id 
INNER JOIN tritech_reporting.customer c ON j.customer_id = c.id
INNER JOIN tritech_reporting.cost_center cc ON j.id = cc.job_id
WHERE j.project_manager_id IN
(
/* SELECT ALL THE DATA */
SELECT j.project_manager_id FROM tritech_reporting.job j 
WHERE cc.type = 'Product' OR cc.type = 'Monitoring' 
OR cc.type = 'Projects Direct' OR cc.type = 'Projects Indirect'
)
AND j.project_manager_id = 7
AND c.company_name LIKE '%spot%'
GROUP BY job_id
ORDER BY job_id DESC;
```